# Push Metrics from Camel to External Service

Tags: apache-camel, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics, datadog, micrometer

I am trying to use camel to push metrics to datadog/cloudwatch. I explored meter and micrometer component, but there is no full-on example on how to actually push metrics data to some external service. I have explored all available examples, and nothing seems give me a proper big picture. . The metrics I require are the stats for each route which is running. Any resource/example which points me there would be really helpful.

Comment: So are you looking for 2 things?

1) How to record Camel metrics via Micrometer?
and 2) How to push metrics from an app into Datadog or CloudWatch? Or do you have the camel metrics coming in and just need help with the Datadog/Cloudwatch part?

Comment: Hi @checketts Sorry if I was not clear. My end goal is to push the metrics from my routes to DataDog/CloudWatch. I couldn't find a direct way to do that. So, I explored the meter/micrometer component and could see some metrics by printing them. Any concrete way to push my metrics to DataDog/Cloud watch is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, please add those details and code snippets of what you've tried by editing the question to include those. That will help folks who are trying to give helpful answers. That way I would know if you are using the DatadogRegistry of micrometer and just need help configuring it.

Answer (score 0):

hawtio is what you need. How many times the route has run .ram consumption, how many classes have been loaded etc . Everything that comes to mind . It has a very nice interface. https://hawt.io/

Comment: Yes. I did a trial with hawt.io and it worked wonderfully in my local environment. But, I was looking into integrating some services which are already known and available like DataDog/CloudWatch.

Answer (score 0):

Publishing metrics to datadog is actually documented: https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/datadog
For CloudWatch, see this PR: https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer-docs/pull/131

If you are using spring-boot, you will get properties support for this.

Comment: I already tried setting up things as mentioned in the document. The counter does not seem to work properly for me. The increment function does not actually increment the value when I use DataDogRegistry. I don't know if I'm getting the settings wrong. There are bits and pieces everywhere. But, one full-on example from camel->micrometer->datadog would have been really great.